# Markdown PDF Knitr - MINUS SIGN (U+2212) error

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr

When knitting my R markdown file to pdf the following error message occurs:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character âˆ’ (U+2212)
>   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
>   markdown

I know it has to do with the MINUS sign I'm using in some formulas, but I can't solve the problem.

I have already set the Typset LaTeX into pdf.

The formulas in question are:

```
\hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
```

and

```
\hat{\beta_0}=\bar{y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}
```

Comment: Your question may be better-suited to https://tex.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177468/why-are-minus-signs-not-working-in-this-equation)

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another method to get around this error is to search and replace the offending unicode character, which can result from copy/pasting code or text into R.

**For your situation, the offending symbol: − (en dash) should be replaced with - (hyphen).**

Your latex can't process the en dash. It's subtle, but these characters have different widths. There are three types of horizontal punctuation “lines”:

- [Hyphen](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/) (-), used to hyphenate compound words and simple compound adjective (hence its name) and often used as the minus sign (-) in math
- [En dash](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/en-dash/) (–), used to mark ranges in numbers, dates, scores and for complex compound adjectives
- [Em dash](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/why-you-should-love-the-em-dash/) (—), used to separate extra information or mark a break in a sentence and other niche writing situations

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem.

---

```
title: "Your Title here"
output:
pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
```

---

Answer (score -1):

A little late but for anyone else who has the same problem:

Use `\-` instead of `-`